# Button overflowed by 37 pixels flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a flutter project, and when I went to test the app on a cell phone, I noticed that no buttons were showing up.

How can I solve this?

Here's what's happening:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2feZ7.png)

This is my code:

https://gist.github.com/anaritacunha2001/8dd091164bca2aa0458a00a55c427c66

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Column(
               children: [_buildData(), _buildTimer(), _buildControls()],
            ),
          ),
       ),
    );
  }
```

Use `SingleChildScrollView` widget